# Can you have a L2 cache without a L1 cache?

Tags: caching, gpu, mali

I'm working on a project about the [Mali 450 GPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKeYP.png). In the diagram I noticed that there is only a level 2 cache which doesn't make sense based on what I have learned in class. From what I understand, the level 1 cache is always the closest and smallest cache, and so this should be labeled the level 1 cache. Or is there a level 1 cache that isn't labeled on the diagram?

Also, as a side question for clarification: Would the level 2 cache be responsible for storing image/video data that could be used/referenced again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The level 1 caches are often not drawn on diagrams such as these because they are integrated within each vertex/fragment processor, whereas the level 2 caches are typically shared between several vertex/fragment processors.

> Would the level 2 cache be responsible for storing image/video data
>   that could be used/referenced again?

Yes; any data that is likely to be used/referenced again.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense. So just to clarify, does that mean that the CPU has one separate L1 cache while the GPU has multiple L1 caches? Referencing back to the diagram I uploaded earlier, would the GPU have a L1 cache for each fragment processor and an additional one in the vertex processor, totaling 9 in the GPU? And none of these L1 caches are shared? Is it because they are so small?

Comment: When you say this, "whereas the level 2 caches are typically shared between several processors", what do you mean by processors? Do you mean frag/vertex processors or CPU/GPU or both?

Comment: In the case of Mali-450 the sharing is between the multiple fragment processors (there can be up to 8, depending on the performance target of the device). The screen is split up into small tiles, and each processor processes one tile at a time (a common approach in mobile GPUs). It's highly likely that neighboring tiles, processed on different fragment shader cores, will share data related to both triangles and textures via the L2.

Comment: Re: does that mean that the CPU has one separate L1 cache while the GPU has multiple L1 caches? Yeah, to a first order of approximation at least. See the first few slides of http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15869-f11/www/lectures/08_mem_hierarchy.pdf for some generic examples.